# How to use Ziggy with Vuex

Tags: laravel, vue.js, ziggy

Is anyone using Ziggy with Vuex? I recently installed Ziggy (https://github.com/tighten/ziggy) so I can use Laravel's named routes in my Vue (2) files. It's working just fine my my Vue components, but it's a different story with Vuex files, where I have a number of axios calls in Vuex actions. The documentation says nothing about vuex modules, and all of my attempts to import the `route` method from the Ziggy vendor package result in either compilation errors or console errors on page load (e.g., `route is not defined`). I've tried:

`import route from '../...relative-path-to.../vendor/tightenco/ziggy/dist/index.js';`

`import route, { ZiggyVue } from 'ziggy';`

and methods suggested elsewhere (https://highlandsolutions.com/blog/how-i-like-to-simplify-ziggys-route-helper)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've got the answer, thanks to some tips from the Ziggy developer. First, Ziggy now comes in an npm package (which I recommend) was well as composer.

`https://www.npmjs.com/package/ziggy-js`

Next, to use Ziggy in a Vuex file, add this to the top of the file (this is my `store.js` file, which imports several Vuex modules):

```
import route from 'ziggy-js'
import { Ziggy }  from '@/routes';
window.route = (name, params, absolute, config = Ziggy) => route(name, params, absolute, config);
```

Note that this is quite different from what you do for Vue components, which need the `ZiggyVue` plugin. For Vuex, you have to import `route()` and set it up.

In a `Vuex` module, you can use Ziggy's `route()` helper method for any axios (or other ajax) calls; e.g.,

```
     const {data} = await axios.get(
        route(
          'api.project.edit_data',
          {id: projectId}
        )
      )
```